# Use bash instead of sh as the shell of choice for python command namespace functions

Tags: python, bash, shell

I need to use a commandline that is suited to bash style, e.g.

```
diff x  <(cat y | tail +2)
```

However, sh -c of the above line gives an error, hence commands.getoutput of the above line fails.
However, bash -c of the above does what I want to get done. Can somebody suggest how to make python use bash.
I understand I can get it done using subprocess, but I have a lot of command lines that I have to process and I want to use only commands.getoutput.

Thanks.

Comment: `commands.getoutput()` is deprecated.  You should use `subprocess.Popen()`.  Any reasons why you don't want to?

Comment: @SvenMarnach: My read of the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/commands.html?highlight=getoutput#commands.getoutput) leads me to believe that, while `commands.getstatus()` is deprecated, `commands.getoutput()` is not.

Comment: @Dennis: Look at the very top of the page you linked.

Comment: @SvenMarnach: Oops! Back to kindergarten for some more reading lessons for me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do `commands.getoutput("bash -c 'diff x  <(tail +2 y)'")`, perhaps (note that `cat` is unnecessary).

However: `commands.getoutput('tail +2 y | diff x -')` doesn't require Bash.

Comment: @SvenMarnach: Oops. I overlooked that one. @JakobBowyer: The OP insists on using it so I just followed his lead.

Comment: +1.  Inspite of the mentioned issues, this is a helpful answer, and it is what the OP requested.